# Issues with constraints

Tags: ios, constraints

So I have 5 Views -  V1, V2, V3, V4 and V5

These views are added to a view which acts as a contained view so I can scroll between them - Like a page controller. This is embedded in a Navigation controller

The issue is that When I set constrain for V2-V5 it does not work unless I hit the home button then come back.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Before
[image]

After I click home button and come back to view
[image]

Comment: Show code and maybe screenshots?

Comment: @ jtbandes Here I added some pictures

Comment: can you show your constraints too.

Comment: @Rohit Pradhan I have all these buttons and label in a stack view and the only constrains I have are trailing space, leading space, bottom space and top space. Thanks btw

Comment: The issue is that When I set constrain for V2-V5 it does not work unless I hit the home button then come back........I didn't get this line

Comment: @Rohit Pradhan Sorry for the confusion. So i have about 5 different view controllers. They are added to one mainViewController which has a school view on top of it. So when I scroll left and right i slide between these view controllers. The mainViewController has a navigation bar embedded.  When i run the app the first view (View1) works out perfect in terms of the constraint. When I slide to view two- the above pictures is what it looks like. In order for the constraint to take effect I have to press command + shift + H then click the app icon on the simulator.

Comment: do you added the constraints in code or in IB

Comment: @JakeC: each 5 view having same design right ? If, reuse the same view. Not need to create different views.

Comment: @Vineesh TP each view does have the same design. When you press the button different audio will come out.

Comment: @ Rohit Pradhan on IB

Comment: @JakeC: I mean Create a View and use the same for 5 views in pageController

Comment: @ Vineesh TP Well I have a mainView with the page controller then I created 5 separate views and added it to that mainView. Is there anyway I can keep it like this. I think the only issue it my top constraint at the moment . any solutions?

Comment: @jakeC.It will be very helpful if you give the screenshot of constraints..I am not able to guess from this screenshots